# Disable media controls on iPhone lockscreen

Tags: ios, control-center

When playing any kind of audio (for example the Music or Spotify app) you see media controls on your lockscreen. They are handy, but also cover the wallpaper I like to see (I can control the music player with my headset). Is there a way to disable those media controls on the lockscreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say, the answer is no. Although I don't find it intrusive to have the controls there, I wish that it wouldn't blur the background, too. The availability of the same controls in the Control Center makes it redundant.

Answer (score 1):

If you press the home button, the controls will be replaced by the full-sized time and date. However, your wallpaper will still be blurry, unfortunately. This will also reset to media controls once the screen goes to sleep again.

Comment: The cover image is also still shown, so the most part is still covered anyway.

Comment: That's true. I guess if you really don't want it covering (heh) the wallpaper, you can remove them from iTunes.

Comment: But that would only work for iTunes but not Spotify or podcast apps

Answer (score 0):

Swipe the screen to your right & then remove all app suggestions via "edit" at the bottom of the screen. That's the best option I found for not allowing unintended access to apps on the lock screen from my pocket

Comment: I am trying to prevent the Audible app from appearing on my lock screen, but when I swipe right and touch "edit", Audible is not listed as a widget.